# Symfony Getter on Class on Relation get unrelated entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, relation, entities

So in Symfony 6, i'm looking for a way of creating a getter in Entity that has a ManyToOne relation, basically this relation has a field that may contain a entity id or not (can be null), if this field is null, I want the getter to append the nulled values into the getter (if this is easier), or create a new getter that contains this entities with the relation as null values.

I'm not sure how to do this as it doesn't seem right to call entity manager inside a entity.

This is some sort of the code I want, but actually using some good practice:

```
    /**
     * @return Collection<int, DocumentCategory>
     */
    public function getPublicDocumentCategories(): Collection
    {
        $publicDocumentService = $this->getRepository(DocumentCategory::class)->find(["country" => null]);

        return $publicDocumentService;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, DocumentCategory>
     */
    public function getDocumentCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->documentCategories;
    }
```

I've looked already and it's bad practice this, but yeah that's the result I need in order to not  repeat code (which also seems a bad practice) and return in all the controllers at twig render this entities.

Comment: DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle is not about how to not repeat yourself always. You can easily google a lot of examples and articles when it is better to repeat the code than doing smth like in your example ;)

Comment: @EvgenyRuban alright, thank you I was a bit skeptical and didn't knew it would be the right way of doing it because like in this case it'll be required in all twig renders, as the data would be inside a menu, but thanks